# Pokemon status move information

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

*I recently asked a similar, but more broad/less thought-out question and it got put on hold. However, I think this one is more on topic.*

In pokemon gen 1, how is the difference between how much status moves affect pokemon set up. for example: whats the difference between poisoning and badly poisoning a pokemon. or raising attack/sharply raising attack

Also, how is it determined how long (how many turns) paralysis/sleep/etc last?

finally are there any status' that have hidden effects? for example, I think I remember reading somewhere that your attack goes down while your burned.

Comment: It's still multiple, mostly unrelated questions, at least one of which is a dupe. Not that I mind answering them- just stick to one question per question in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stat changes in gen 1 used the same modifiers- 1.5x, 2x, 2.5x, 3x, 3.5x, 4x for increases and 2/3, 2/4, 2/5, 2/6, 2/7, 2/8 for decreases- as in later generations. Changing a stat moves it up or down one step, sharply changing it moves it up or down two steps.

Poison deals 1/16 of a targets max hp per turn. Toxic uses a formula which increases the damage it does each round. The first hit does 1/16, the second does 2/16, the third does 3/16 and so on.

Sleep in generation I lasts from 1-7 turns, selected randomly. This value is set when the pokemon falls asleep. All other status effects last until healed.

Burn halves the attack stat of the affected pokemon. Paralysis reduces a pokemon's speed by 75%. The other effects of status should be apparent.

Comment: as for the hp decrementation properties of burn, is this a constant 1/16?

Comment: @LukeP In generation I, yes.